# Reading gzip file without any extension is failing in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Currently i am facing a issue where while trying to read files from ADL gen2 RAW layer is failing because of there is no file extension added there. These files are basically json files which are zip compressed. And i am using autoloader in general to read the other files so that the incremental files are get picked daily basis.
But for few of the sources the ingestion process is not adding file extension and doing a binary copy to RAW. I understand that these can be fixed in the ADF pipeline while ingestion.
But i want to explore if this can be handled at all within databricks scope. Below is the example of my exact folder structure. Like this for year 2020 there can be different folders for different month and day and then timestamp. for example the screenshot is for 15th November 2020 and 23 is the timestamp.

[image]

```py
if rawFileType == 'json':
    raw_df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \     
       .option("cloudFiles.format", rawFileType) \ 
       .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes",inferColumnTypeValue) \ 
       .option("mergeSchema", "true") \ 
       .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation",schemaPath) \ 
       .option("cloudFiles.allowOverwrites","true") \ 
       .option("ignoreCorruptFiles", "true") \ 
       .option("header",headerValue) \ 
       .option("compression","gzip") \ 
       .option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles",True) \ 
       .option("checkpointLocation",checkpointPath) \ 
       .option("modifiedAfter",modifiedAfterValue) \ 
       .load(rawPath)
```

Please suggest if there is any way this can be handled through databricks.

Comment: Post your code. Post the errors you're getting.

Comment: f rawFileType == 'json':
            raw_df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")\
.option("cloudFiles.format", rawFileType)\
.option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes",inferColumnTypeValue)\
.option("mergeSchema", "true")\
.option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation",schemaPath)\
.option("cloudFiles.allowOverwrites","true")\
.option("ignoreCorruptFiles", "true")\
.option("header",headerValue)\
.option("compression","gzip")\
.option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles",True)\
.option("checkpointLocation",checkpointPath)\
.option("modifiedAfter",modifiedAfterValue)\
.load(rawPath)

Comment: added it to your OP. I'll wait for -> "Post the errors you're getting."

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution is you can move the data from files not having extension to file having extension using `dbutils.fs.mv()`

below is the original file and number records in it.

[image]

Now below is the file without any extension which gives `_corrupt_record`.

[image]

Run below code for creating files with extension.

```
def add_extensions(path):
    files = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
    for fi in files:
        if fi.name.endswith(".gz"):
            continue
        elif fi.isDir():
            add_extensions(fi.path)
            continue
        new_file = path + fi.name + ".gz"
        curr_file = path + fi.name
        print(curr_file,new_file)
        dbutils.fs.mv(curr_file,new_file)

path = "abfss://data@jgsadls.dfs.core.windows.net/json_data/"
add_extensions(path)
```

After running this your file extension will be changed.

[image]

After running your query got the successful result.

[image]

Comment: The problem is inside the main folder there are several sub folders and then the actual file is present. I tried your above code , only change i made is recursion = true i set. but because of the subfolders it is giving me
An error occurred while calling o405.mv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Operation failed: "This operation is not permitted as the path is too deep."

Comment: and instead of mounting i am using abfss path directly
Your_mount_path = 'abfss://main-data@dentanalyticsdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/PIGEON_MIF/AEL_EVENTS_DEVICE_COLLECTOR_METADATA/'
files = dbutils.fs.ls(Your_mount_path)
for fi in files:
    if fi.name.endswith(".gz"):
        continue
    new_file = Your_mount_path + fi.name + ".gz"
    curr_file = Your_mount_path + fi.name
    dbutils.fs.mv(curr_file,new_file,recurse=True)

Comment: while you do read stream how you are handling the subfolders. The main folder is `.gz` right? Inside it many folders are there? And you are getting correct path when you list down the files? check it by printing `files` in above code.

Comment: @sayannandi  I've updated the code in solution. Try it.

Comment: so while doing readstream i just give till the main folder which is the name of the dataset. for say the dataset name is "ABC" so i will give "abfss://{root_folder}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/json_data/ABC/" . Inside ABC there are multiple layers of subfolders and in the end the actual file without extension. Like in my problem statement you can see that inside 2020 there is 12/15/23. so like this there can be 2020/12/16/24,2020/12/17/25,2020/11/01/01 like this

Comment: so it's like year/mm/dd/timetsamp/file

Comment: @sayannandi Yeah got it. I've updated solution for the same. Loop through multiple folders and adds extension.